# return to page when not allowed php

Tags: php

i made an login system as an exersize with functions. if you got the function owner you can acess `employees.php`

this works fine but if i edi the current user it still allows me to go to this page.

this is the code of `employees.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']) === false){
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    if($_SESSION['function'] != 'owner'){
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/employees.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <div>
            <?php
                echo "<a href='home.php'><img src='images/home.png'></a>";

             if(isset($_SESSION['id']) === true){
                echo "<a class='nav-item' href='stockpage.php'>Vooraad</a>";
                echo "<a class='nav-item' href='orderpage.php'>Bestellingen</a>";
                
            }   
            if($_SESSION['function'] == 'owner'){
                echo "<a class='nav-item' href='employees.php'>Medewerkers</a>";
            }

            ?>
            
        </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['id']) === false){
            echo "<a class='nav-item' href='index.php'>login</a>";
        }
        else{
            $username = $_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname'];
            echo "<a class='nav-item' href='userpage.php'>".$username."</a>";
        }
        ?>

    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <?php
      
        include "../admin-webshop/classes/dbh.class.php";
        include "../admin-webshop/classes/adminuser.class.php";
        include "../admin-webshop/classes/adminuserview.class.php";
        $adminuserview = new AdminUserView();
        $adminuserview->showAdminUsers();
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code that brings me back to `employees.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['change_submit'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $adres = $_POST['adres'];
    $function = $_POST['function'];
    $active = $_POST['active'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $adminusercontr = new AdminUserContr(); 
    $adminusercontr->changeAdminUser($firstname,$lastname,$email,$phone,$adres,$function,$active,$id);
    header("location: ../employees.php");

}
```

Comment: Do you specifically mean that you expect `$_SESSION['function'] != 'owner'` to be `true` but are observing it to be `false`?  If so, what is the value in `$_SESSION['function']`?  Where do you set that value?

Comment: You need to put `die();` after each of the `header("Location...` calls, otherwise PHP will continue executing and output the supposedly-restricted content anyway - it will visible to anyone who looks using their browser's developer tools, or to anyone accessing the site using a a HTTP client which doesn't automatically follow redirect headers.

Comment: We don't know what the `changeAdminUser()` function does, but unless it also updates the current $_SESSION values as well as the database, then any changes you make to the user's function won't take effect until they log out and log back in again.